# pandas - get shifted value in apply function

Tags: python, pandas, apply, shift

In a DataFrame I have two columns A and B.
I would like to add a new column which contains new value calculated based on A and B column's current and previous row.
My first approach was to use *apply* function

```py
def calc_C(A,B):
    if A.shift() > A:
        C = B + B.shift(1)...
    else:
        C = ..
    return C

df["C"] = df.apply(lambda x: calc_C(x["A"],x["B"]),axis=1)
```

But I cant access the shift function, because those parametres are float64 objects.
I also tried other way, but now in a if statement it tries to compare whole series.

```py
def calc_C(df):
    if df["A"] > df["A"].shift() 
        C= df["B"] + df["B"].shift()
    else:
        C = ..
    return C
df["C"] = calc_C(df)
```

How can I do this pythonic pandas way without copying the dataset and creating new temporary columns?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your input DataFrame along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need to create new columns in your DataFrame, but it would be a lot more efficient to work with Series objects in a vectorized manner. Here is some sample code

```
a_shifted = df["A"].shift()
b_shifted = df["B"].shift()
df["C"] = np.where(df["A"] > a_shifted, df["B"] + b_shifted, ...)
```

Comment: can this be done when the resulting C value is calculated by function which takes all 4 parameters? e.g. in case when A  > a_shifted its `foo(A,a_shifted,B,B_shifted)`? and in other case its similiar function

Comment: A function works as long as it returns a series with the same index as the data frame you are looking to add C to, though if that is your function signature it is likely easier to pass the data frame and just have a_shifted and b_shifted calculated as shown above